# PHP/SQLSRV: 3 query problems

Tags: php, sql, database, unicode, sqlsrv

I'm running IIS 6.1 with PHP5.3 and SQL Server 2014 on Windows 7. My database is based on my iTunes playlist. The script I'm currently working on receives the name of a band from a form, then returns a table with each album by that band, showing the name and year for each album, then the track number, name and length of each song on that album. It works fine for most of my albums, but there are three problems:

1. Non-Latin characters don't show up. I have music in several different languages, and I can query just fine using Unicode characters in SQL Server, but when I try to return these results on the web, all the non-Latin characters show up as question marks. The answers to this problem that I've seen didn't fix my problem (for example, adding a header and meta tags to set the page as UTF-8).
2. One particular album (Larks' Tongues in Aspic by King Crimson) bungs up the query, presumably because of the single quote in the album title. What's weird is that the album title shows up just fine, but not the tracks on that album. Other songs and albums with single quotes in the name don't cause problems, only this particular album/song. I've tried every combination of escaping single quotes I could think of, and they all cause the query to fail even harder. I've turned magic quotes on and off with no result. As written below, the query returns this error:

   ```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 
   [code] => 102 [2] =>         [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
   [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Tongues'. [message] => [Microsoft]
   [SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Tongues'. ) 
   [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 105 [code] => 105 
   [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]
   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' ORDER BY TrackNumber'.    
   [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]
   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' ORDER BY TrackNumber'. ) )
   ```
3. I can't figure out how to include wildcards in the query. For example, if I search for "Alison Krauss", I only get results for Alison herself. If I want to search for songs where Alison is one of multiple artists (for example, Alison Krauss & Union Station), I'd need to add a wildcard to the query, but I can't figure out how to do that, either by adding it to the variable passed into the query, or in the query itself.

Here is the code:

```
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    require_once ('connect.php');

    echo '<table align = center cellpadding = 2 cellspacing = 2>';

    $band = stripslashes($_REQUEST['band']);

    $albumqry = "SELECT AlbumName, AlbumYear FROM vw_AlbumTracks WHERE ArtistName LIKE '$band'         
    GROUP BY AlbumName, AlbumYear ORDER BY AlbumYear";

    $ayqry = SQLSRV_QUERY($conn, $albumqry);
    if( $ayqry === false )
    {
         echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    while ($record = SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY ($ayqry)) {

    $album = $record['AlbumName'];

    echo '<tr><td colspan=3><b>' . $album . ' (' . $record['AlbumYear'] . ')</b></td></tr>';

    $query = "SELECT TrackNumber, SongName, SongLength FROM vw_AlbumTracks WHERE ArtistName                 
    LIKE N'$band' AND AlbumName LIKE N'$album' ORDER BY TrackNumber";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);
    if( $stmt === false )
    {
         echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    while( $track = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo '<tr><td width = 5>' . $track['TrackNumber'] . '.</td>
    <td width = 300>' . $track[stripslashes('SongName')] . '</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">' . $track['SongLength'] . '</right></td></tr>';

    }

    echo '<tr></tr>';

    }

    echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved two of my own problems.

1. Adding wildcards: added the wildcard(s) and the N (for entering Unicode characters) into the variable definition. For example:

   ```
   $band = "N'" . stripslashes($_POST['band']) . "%'";
   $albumqry = "SELECT AlbumName, AlbumYear FROM vw_AlbumTracks WHERE ArtistName 
   LIKE $band GROUP BY AlbumName, AlbumYear ORDER BY AlbumYear";
   ```
2. Escaping the single quotes in the PHP passed into an SQL query: used str_replace in conjunction with addslashes to first escape the troublesome single quotes, then re-escape them in a manner that SQL understands.

   ```
   $album = "N'" . str_replace("\'", "''", addslashes($record['AlbumName'])) . "'";
   ```

Still totally lost on the Unicode thing, though. I added echo $band; to the page, and after entering 윤하 to the form on the previous page, it displays N'윤하%', which is exactly what it's supposed to pass in to SQL Server, but the trace in SQL Server Profiler shows the query as

```
    SELECT AlbumName, AlbumYear FROM vw_AlbumTracks 
    WHERE ArtistName LIKE N'ìœ¤í•˜%' 
    GROUP BY AlbumName, AlbumYear ORDER BY AlbumYear
```

So somehow the Unicode is getting garbled on the way from PHP to SQL Server, both of which are capable of displaying it correctly on their own.